# Is there any way to list types of interface's properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Inter {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

let variable:(blabla);
             => right here.
```

I want to set the above to `(number | string)` using `Inter`'s properties.
Is there any way to do this? Thanks for reading !

Comment: is this what you meant? type InterTypes = Inter['a'] | Inter['b']; let variable: InterTypes = 'hello';

Comment: @bhoo-day I mean a interface may change, so I wanted to list only by interface name wihtout typing for a and b. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type query with a type that is a union of all keys, which you can get `keyof`:

```
let val: Inter[keyof Inter]; // will be string | number
```

Comment: That's right about it. I didn't know that it works. You've helped me a lot. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
let val: typeon Inter.a | val: typeon Inter.b
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry there was not enough explanation, I wanted to be listed automatically. Manually I usually use it like this. let variable:(Inter['a'] | Inter['b']);